# Does Apple provide a way to determine why a specific code is deprecated?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm currently maintaining legacy code project that requires me to resolve deprecation warnings for outdated iOS versions. Looking through documentation as well as Xcode warnings, I'm able to determine which methods are deprecated and recommendations on which methods should be used to replace deprecated code.

Out of curiosity, is there a way we can determine why a specific code was deprecated? Is there a system design explanation that tells us devs why this deprecation was needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to prove a negative (i.e., showing that the reason for a deprecation is _not_ documented anywhere), but in general, the answer is: no, not explicitly. Often, API is deprecated because it has a more modern/powerful/expressive alternative, or because the old code was sufficiently harmful as to require replacement. I don't know if there will be a significantly more satisfying answer for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything built into the documentation. But by looking at the header and the replacement, and/or by watching the relevant WWDC video, you can usually get the point. (I've certainly never had any difficulty with this.)